# How to call static library function from share library?

Tags: android, c++, c, android-ndk, ndk-build

I have an already build static library(main.a for armv64-v8a architecture) which have a main.cpp at its root folder which expose a static function like following:

`void main::global(void * _o, void * _i);`

My requirement is to build a wrapper in android and call this function from the android application.

I have tried following:

- Created a jni folder.
- Created a jni/static/arm64-v8a folder.
- Moved main.o in the above folder.
- Created a new file in jni folder named export.cpp and written following code into this:

```
    #include <jni.h>
    #include <string.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>
    #include <main.h>

    JNIEXPORT void JNICALL Java_com_example_test_sendData(JNIEnv *env, jobject obj, jbyteArray outData, jbyteArray inData)
    {
    }
```

- Created an Application.mk file under jni folder with following contents

```
APP_ABI := arm64-v8a
APP_PLATFORM := android-23
```

- Created an Android.mk file under jni folder with following contents:

```
LOCAL_PATH := $(call my-dir)

########################
# prepare static lib
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := main
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := static/$(TARGET_ARCH_ABI)/main.a
include $(PREBUILT_STATIC_LIBRARY)
########################

########################
# prepare export
include $(CLEAR_VARS)
LOCAL_MODULE    := export
LOCAL_SRC_FILES := export.cpp
LOCAL_STATIC_LIBRARIES := main
include $(BUILD_SHARED_LIBRARY)
########################
```

Now, if I run `ndk-build` command then it will throw an error like following:

```
[arm64-v8a] Compile++      : export <= export.cpp
jni/export.cpp:4:10: fatal error: 'main.h' file not found
#include <main.h>
         ^~~~~~~~~
1 error generated.
make: *** [obj/local/arm64-v8a/objs/export/export.o] Error 1
```

Please help me to resolve this issue.

Tried to change `#include <main.h>` to `#include "main.h"` but it doesn't work and throw same error.

Comment: `main.h` is not a standard header.

Comment: I have also tried `#include "main.h"` but even that is not working.